# Нейронная сеть для предсказания временных рядов

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras

друзья!

В данный момент я пытаюсь написать нейронную сеть на основе keras, которая сможет делать предсказания во временном ряду. Временной ряд имеет вид 0...0 N 0...0 N 0...0, где числа N встречаются с одной и той же частотой. Так, например, на входном векторе (1000 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 1000 0 0 0) моя нейронная сеть по задумке должна вернуть 1000. Для написания сети я использую LSTM-слои, так как мне важно наличие памяти у нейросети. Мой код на данный момент имеет вид

```
model =  Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(60, activation = softplus, use_bias = True, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1, sample)))
model.add(LSTM(60, activation = softplus, use_bias = True, return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(60, activation = softplus, use_bias = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.05))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss = 'MSE',
              optimizer = 'RMSProp',
              metrics = ['accuracy', 'mae'])
model.fit(
        x = trainX, y = trainY, 
        batch_size = batch_size, 
        epochs = 1000,
        shuffle=True,
        validation_data=(testX, testY),
        callbacks = [cp_callback])
```

Однако, эта модель работает не очень хорошо: потери на выходе достаточно большие и в процессе обучения они не уменьшаются. Я бьюсь с этой задачей больше недели.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так? И как исправить код, чтобы моя нейросеть работала лучше?

Спасибо за ответ!

З.Ы.: я новичок в нейронных сетях, эта модель будет вторая в моей жизни, поэтому прошу прощения, если задаю глупый вопрос. Всем добра :)

Comment: Сколько у вас элементов в обучающей выборке?

Comment: Около 5500, это тренировочные вместе с validation

Comment: По-моему, это слишком маленькая выборка для LSTM. Попробуйте использовать FBProphet